# Need of API-Certificate when using Paypal REST API

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

I have a merchant account and use the PayPal-REST-API on my webshop. So I have a ClientID and a Secret to make the REST-API working.

Last week I got a mail from Paypal with the hint to renew my API-Certificate. After a bit research on the Paypal-Developer-Portal I found out that the certificate is used for the NVP/SOAP-API-Integration.

So my questions are, is there a dependency beetween NVP/SOAP-API and the REST-API and do I need to renew the API-Certificate when using PayPal-REST-API?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For NVP/SOAP-API, it is for the Express Checkout and the legacy integration. As for REST API is for the new integration where it uses client id and secret. It depends on the API that you use.

Thank you.